# Show specific information from mysql to dropdownbox in php html.

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select, dropdown

These is my code to get the information from the database. So status is the one where in my database would be either Interested or Not Interested.

```
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ID =$row['Particulars_ID'];
    $name = $row['Name'];
    $number =$row['Number'];
    $status =$row['Status'];
    $remarks =$row['Remarks'];  
}
```

I would like to echo out the value Not Interested if my database shows that this person is not interested. However from my below code, it always show Interested no matter which person i click on.

```
echo "<select name = 'status', id = status>
        <option value='Interested'>Interested</option>
        <option value='Not Interested'>Not Interested</option>
    </select><br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

first - you do not need the comma in the select, second - ensure that this is the only element with the id of status, third - simply check the $status value in each option and echo selected if it is.

```
echo "<select name = 'status' id = 'status'>
        <option value='Interested'";
           if($status == "Interested"){echo " selected";}
        echo">Interested</option>
        <option value='Not Interested' ";
           if($status == "Not Interested"){echo " selected";}
        echo">Not Interested</option>
    </select><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
echo "<select name = 'status', id = status>
        <option value='Interested'>Interested</option>
        <option value='Not Interested'>Not Interested</option>
    </select><br>";
```

to this

```
// Set the selected attributes based on the value of status
$interested = ($status === 'Interested') ? ' selected' : '';
$notInterested = ($interested === '') ? ' selected' : '';

echo <<< SELECT
<select name="status" id="status">
    <option$interested>Interested</option>
    <option$notInterested>Not Interested</option>
</select>
SELECT;
```

You don't need the value attribute if the value is the same as the text.

If there were more than two options, I recommend a loop like this:

```
<?php foreach ($options as $o) : ?>
    <option<?php if ($o === $optionValue) ?> selected<?php endif ?>><?= optionValue ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

since the default is the first option `Interested`, then `if ($status === "Not Interested")` set the [`option` attribute `selected`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

```
<?php

if ($status === "Not Interested") $selected = "selected";
else $selected = "";

echo "<select name = 'status', id = status>
        <option value='Interested'>Interested</option>
        <option value='Not Interested' $selected>Not Interested</option>
    </select><br>";
```